# Excel keeps freezing when running this code

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a function from a command button(ActiveX) and when I run it, excel freezes every other time or so. Does anyone see why?

The code copies a range from an empty formatted sheet, and inserts it into a worksheet where the command button is placed(to insert a new month there).

```
Function nyMndFunction(navnArk As String)
Dim gammelMnd As String
Dim nyMnd As String
Dim wstEnt As Worksheet
Dim wstMal As Worksheet
Dim insertRange As Range

Set wstMal = Worksheets("Mal")
Set wstEnt = Worksheets(navnArk)

wstMal.Range(wstMal.Cells(1, 1), wstMal.Cells(41, 11)).Copy

gammelMnd = wstEnt.Cells(4, 2).Value

Select Case gammelMnd
    Case "JANUAR"
        nyMnd = "FEBRUAR"
    Case "FEBRUAR"
        nyMnd = "MARS"
    Case "MARS"
        nyMnd = "APRIL"
    Case "APRIL"
        nyMnd = "MAI"
    Case "MAI"
        nyMnd = "JUNI"
    Case "JUNI"
        nyMnd = "JULI"
    Case "JULI"
        nyMnd = "AUGUST"
    Case "AUGUST"
        nyMnd = "SEPTEMBER"
    Case "SEPTEMBER"
        nyMnd = "OKTOBER"
    Case "OKTOBER"
        nyMnd = "NOVEMBER"
    Case "NOVEMBER"
        nyMnd = "DESEMBER"
    Case "DESEMBER"
        nyMnd = "JANUAR"
End Select

wstEnt.Range("B4").Insert Shift:=xlDown
wstEnt.Cells(4, 2).Value = nyMnd
wstEnt.Cells(3, 3).Select
End Function
```

and then I call it with this in 8 different worksheets

```
Private Sub cmd_NyMndBravida_Click()
    Dim navnArk As String

    navnArk = ActiveSheet.Name
    nyMndFunction (navnArk)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's for the `CutCopyMode` mode kept active after `wstEnt.Range("B4").Insert Shift:=xlDown`

so insert `Application.CutCopyMode = False` statement just after that line:

```
Function nyMndFunction(navnArk As String)
    Dim gammelMnd As String, monthNames As String

    ...

    wstEnt.Range("B4").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Application.CutCopyMode = False '<-- statement to be inserted

    wstEnt.Cells(4, 2).value = nyMnd
    wstEnt.Cells(3, 3).Select
End Function
```

Furthermore you may want to consider the following shortened down code:

**code attached to the button**

```
Private Sub cmd_NyMndBravida_Click()

    nyMndFunction ActiveSheet '<--| just pass the worksheet itself, without having to evaluate its name here and then evaluate it back to the worksheet object in 'nyMndFunction'

End Sub
```

**nyMndSub**

since it doesn't return anything it's a `Sub`, so let's write it and name it as such!

```
Option Explicit

Sub nyMndSub(wstEnt As Worksheet)
    Dim monthNames As String, nyMnd As String
    Dim iMonth As Long
    Dim wstMal As Worksheet

    Set wstMal = Worksheets("Mal")

    monthNames = "JANUAR,FEBRUAR,MARS,APRIL,MAI,JUNI,JULI,AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OKTOBER,NOVEMBER,DESEMBER" '<--| month names list string

    iMonth = InStr(monthNames, wstEnt.Cells(4, 2).value) '<--| look for the cell content in the month names list
    If iMonth > 0 Then '<--| if found...
        iMonth = Len(Left(monthNames, iMonth)) - Len(Replace(Left(monthNames, iMonth), ",", "")) + 1 '<--| get its "position" inside the list by counting the delimiter occurrences before it and skip to the "next" one
        If iMonth = 12 Then iMonth = 0 '<--| if the "next position" is outside the 12-elements month names list then skip back to the first element
        nyMnd = Split(monthNames, ",")(iMonth) '<--| get the month names in the finally selected "position"

        wstMal.Range(wstMal.Cells(1, 1), wstMal.Cells(41, 11)).Copy '<-- do the copy juts when needed
        With wstEnt
            .Range("B4").Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| exit cutcopymode as soon as possible, i.e. after the clipboard content hs been exploited and no longer needed
            .Cells(4, 2).value = nyMnd
            .Cells(3, 3).Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

where it's used the [Split()]/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528.aspx) function to return an array out of a string with delimiters

as you can see from the linked documentation, it return a zero-based array so that the above code cope with it when dealing with `iMonth` index

Comment: Thank you for solving, and giving me constructive advice on my code! I really appreciate it :)